<use> tag to show svg not working in new version 126.0.6478.57
Today, I updated chorme up to version 126.0.6478.57
My issue:
 tag to show svg not working, I tried load my website in edge browser and chorme in my phone it still working.
I searched google and find some issue like this but it not resloved my issue.
I tried change
<use href={`${sprite}#${iconId}`}></use>

to
<use xlinkHref={`${sprite}#${iconId}`}></use>

but not working.

What does the output look like in the browser inspector? <use href="something#another"></use>?

right, this is html in dev tool


Can the issue be reproduced in a new Chrome incognito window? Does it affect Firefox as well?

i tried in Chrome incognito not working, firefox still working, it's bug of Chorme browser?

I can produce a similar problem with href in Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox. So it's a Chromium bug. This is the most similar issue I found in the bug tracker: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/346756469

I got the information, thank you

@DatTran Did you find a fix for this issue?

I only update new version and it's working again

Please check out your icon file format. I had the same issue. Should be something like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>...


tks you, but bugs fixed in new version
